# Flutter Search screen not building filtered Listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a simple search screen in Flutter. I have the search text field working in the appbar widget, and it prints the correct results of any search i make.
However the ListView in the body of the screen is not building when I setState.

I'd really appreciate if you could let me know what I am missing here.

Many thanks.

Here is my code:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      leading: BackButton(
        color: qigangButtonColor,
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: searchBarColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (text) {
              print(text);
              _searchExercises.clear();
              if (text.isEmpty) {
                setState(() {});
                return;
              }
              setState(() {
                _searchExercises =
                    Provider.of<Exercises>(context, listen: false)
                        .exercisesSearch(text);
                _searchExercises.forEach((element) {
                  print(element.title);
                });
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                hintText: 'Search...',
                border: InputBorder.none),
          ),
        ),
      )),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      height: deviceHeight * 0.90,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _searchExercises.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            print(_searchExercises.length);
            return Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25, top: 25),
              child: MainCard(
                exercise: _searchExercises[index],
                cardHeight: containerHeight,
                cardWidth: containerWidth,
              ),
            );
          }),
    ),
  ),
);
```

To add a little more detail. There are two debug print statements. The one in the app bar always the correct values in _searchExercises.

However the one in the Listview builder is never showing. So it would seem that it is never actually building the list view.

Comment: Where did you instantiate the `_searchExercises` variable? If it is inside the `build` method, put it out. I assume you are using `Stateful` widgets as you are calling `setState`.

Comment: Yes it wasn't outside the build method. It's working well now thanks